# how to add active to a tag and li tag with php

Tags: php, arrays

Trying to get my PHP navigation bar to work. I am trying to echo the page where the user is on with the attached class of active if the page is current.

Here is my code. It shows the links and I can navigate the site but it ignores the active class. Hover works and links are styled. It just ignores the active class.

```
<?php
$pages = array(
    "index.php" => "Home", 
    "pages/contact.php" => "Contact Us", 
    "pages/services.php" => "services", 
    "pages/employees.php" => "Employees", 
    "pages/dashboard.php" => "Dashboard");

foreach ($pages as $url => $label) {
  echo '<li ';

  if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == $url) {
    echo '"class=active"';
  }
  echo '><a href=', "$url", '>', "$label", '</a></li>';
}
?>
```

Comment: What are you sending in query string ( get variable ), are you sending 'page'?

Comment: im grabbing the page off each page like this at the top <?php $page = 'contact'; ?>

Comment: I mean are you sending a get variable like: index.php?page=index.php

Comment: Use `echo $_GET['page']` to see what's in it. Is it the same as for example `pages/services.php`? Probably `$_GET['page']` is never equal to `$url`, so you need to look for the problem there.

Comment: nothing echos out hmmm..

Comment: ya cause everything looks great accept its not adding the active class. so if isset is not getting page. inside of my file I am adding it like this <?php $page = 'index.php'; ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$pages = array(
    "index.php" => "Home", 
    "pages/contact.php" => "Contact Us", 
    "pages/services.php" => "services", 
    "pages/employees.php" => "Employees", 
    "pages/dashboard.php" => "Dashboard");

$cururl = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

foreach ($pages as $url => $label) {
  echo '<li';

  if (strpos($cururl,$url)!==false) {
    echo ' class="active"';
  }
  echo '><a href=', "$url", '>', "$label", '</a></li>';
}
?>
```

This should work for you. Because, you were trying to access the url address using `GET-METHOD`. Here, I have fetched your url by doing `$cururl = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` and checked for the active menu item as `if (strpos($cururl,$url)!==false)`

Comment: what do you mean using the $Get method? on each page? im storing the page like this <?php $page = 'pages/services.php'; ?>

Comment: To make this menu work, your url shoud look like: http://example.com/index.php?page=index.php | http://example.com/index.php?page=pages/services.php | http://example.com/index.php?page=pages/contact.php

 (if you are not using htaccess to re-write yet)

Comment: How are you trying to access your page? code above is now clean, if you are still not getting that work, probably, you are mistaking to access the url in correct way

Comment: what do you mean access the url? your looking at the bav is what i posted. In each file im using the include function and adding the page variable at the top of the page as I showed you. Also I am adding base to each head tag.

Comment: Could you kindly get me the link from where you can navigate to "contact" page? your example link please.

Comment: exactly. That's not get method used. Let me have a fix for this, wait me to edit my answer.

Comment: if you look at the link i gave you, you can see it broke the code.

Comment: Did you start it with `<?php` well??

Comment: yes. it I fixed it. It still does not work. How can I just add a Get function to each page wouldnt that be easier?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48186/discussion-between-prakash-and-nicho)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
echo 'class="active"';
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this :

```
$pages = array(
    "index.php" => "Home", 
    "pages/contact.php" => "Contact Us", 
    "pages/services.php" => "services", 
    "pages/employees.php" => "Employees", 
    "pages/dashboard.php" => "Dashboard");

foreach ($pages as $url => $label) {
  echo '<li ';

  if(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])== basename($url)){   // this line
        echo "class='active'";                              // this line
   }                                                        // and this line
  echo '><a href=', "$url", '>', "$label", '</a></li>';
}
?>
```

Comment: is there a get variable there ?

Comment: no do I need to add Get in it? how do I write it in to this <?php $page = 'index.php'; ?>

Comment: what exactly your url is right now, copy and paste it here

Comment: Hmm. Is the way were doing this only adding active to li? cause I need active on li and <a> could that be the problem?

Comment: no it still dosnt work. is it not because i need to add $Get to the $page = page.php on each page some how?

Comment: ok so at the top of each page I should be showing <?php $page = 'pages/contact.php'; ?>
 and then add the code to my code you posted?

Comment: No, I updated my answer, just do that, change nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === "/page") echo 'id="active"'; 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested:

```
<?php
$pages = array(
    "index.php" => "Home", 
    "contact.php" => "Contact Us", 
    "services.php" => "services", 
    "employees.php" => "Employees", 
    "dashboard.php" => "Dashboard");

$uri = explode("/", stripslashes($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));

foreach ($pages as $url => $label) {
  echo '<li ';
  echo in_array($url, $uri)?'class="active"':'';
  echo '><a href="'.$url.'">'.$label.'</a></li>';
}
?>
```

Note: it is a best practice to put your other page files in the root next to yout index.php